# android -Expandable Notifications not showing big images

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to make a notification that has a big images. I've searched and find some codes and did my customization but it doesn't show the big image . this is my code ;

```
private class sendNotification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap remote_picture = null;
    Context ctx;
    String message;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream in;
        message = "msg";

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://website.com/img.png");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Create the style object with BigPictureStyle subclass.
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("Big Picture Expanded");
        notiStyle.setSummaryText("Nice big picture.");

        // Add the big picture to the style.
        notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an ResultActivity to receive.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(FistActiivty.this, FistActiivty.class);

        // This ensures that the back button follows the recommended
        // convention for the back key.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(FistActiivty.this);

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself).
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(FistActiivty.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(FistActiivty.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(false).setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent).setContentTitle("Big Picture Normal")
                .setContentText("This is an example of a Big Picture Style.").setStyle(notiStyle).build();
        notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
    }
}
```

when the activity runs . it shows the notification but it doesn't show the image .

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Once I had a similar problem and found out that a small image is required, otherwise notifications may behave strangely. So try adding a small image too.

Answer (score 3):

May be the image is too large or you are not expanding the image(by pulling it down).

you can also set the priority of your notification. This may expand your notification image automatically.

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The underlying reason is that these notifications are only expanded if they are the one at the top of a person's notification drawer. Jaspinder's answer works because you are basically forcing the notification to be at the top. Is it reliable? no, because you're competing against other apps for the top spot on the phone, but it's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Set the priority of your notification in notification activity. and also keep image size small.

.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)